# Trying to check if someone is trying to guess my pw on my laptop

Tags: macos

Running macOS Big Sur.

When one physically closes a Macbook and reopens it, one has to re-input the password to log back in.

Is there a log history of this? I'm trying to check if someone is trying to guess my pw on my laptop.

The 'last' command doesn't seem to work. It's giving me big gaps between days (ex. Apr 7, then a big jump to Apr 10).

Any advice?

Big Sur does not seem to have accountpolicy.log anymore to check login attempts.